# Recursive clean up column in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, recursion

I have a table that needs clean up based on search criteria.

```
Create table dbo.tempNames(ID int null, Name varchar(500) null)
INSERT INTO dbo.tempNames values(1,'ABC Financial')
INSERT INTO dbo.tempNames values(1,'ABC Financial Company')
INSERT INTO dbo.tempNames values(1,'ABC Financial Company solely in its capacity')
INSERT INTO dbo.tempNames values(1,'ABC Financial in its capacity')
```

I have a rule that says remove everything after particular substring 1) solely 2) in its capacity

HEre's what I wrote

```
SELECT ID, CASE WHEN Name LIKE '%in its capacity%' THEN SUBSTRING(Name,1,charindex('In Its Capacity',Name,1)-1)
                WHEN Name LIKE '%solely%' THEN  SUBSTRING(Name,1,charindex('solely',Name,1)-1)
                ELSE Name END As ChangedName
                FROM dbo.tempNames
```

For row#3, ChangedName becomes 'ABC Financial Company solely'. How can I recursively do this until all the strings are updated.

Expected output

```
Create table dbo.outputNames(ID int null, ChangedName varchar(500) null)
INSERT INTO dbo.outputNames values(1,'ABC Financial')
INSERT INTO dbo.outputNames values(1,'ABC Financial Company')
INSERT INTO dbo.outputNames values(1,'ABC Financial Company')
INSERT INTO dbo.outputNames values(1,'ABC Financial')
```

Thanks

Comment: I recommend Nolan's answer; as an aside the simplest way for your query is to change the order of your case statement so the '%solely%' check is first (case statements are evaluated in the order they're written).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It the another sample, searching all the keywords and get the first place.

```
SELECT ID,a.pos,LEFT(Name,ISNULL(a.pos,LEN(name))) AS changename
FROM dbo.tempNames
CROSS APPLY( SELECT MIN(NULLIF(c.pos,0)) AS pos FROM 
 (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' solely',Name)),(CHARINDEX(' in its capacity',Name))) c(pos)
) a
```

```
ID          pos         changename
----------- ----------- --------------
1           NULL        ABC Financial
1           NULL        ABC Financial Company
1           22          ABC Financial Company 
1           14          ABC Financial
```

Comment: REPLACE will not work for this case INSERT INTO dbo.tempNames values(1,'ABC Financial Company solely in its capacity blah blah blah'). I want everything removed after the substring.